# The Graphics.MeasureString method is not accurate on windows mobile

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile

The [Graphics.MeasureString(string, Font)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx) method is not accurate on windows mobile. Is there a solution for the problem?

```
public static string GetSubString(Graphics graphic, Font font, 
                                                    string text, int availableWidth)
{
    string tempString = string.Empty;

    Size stringSize = graphic.MeasureString(text, font).ToSize();
    if (stringSize.Width < availableWidth)
    {
        return text;
    }

    for (int index = text.Length-1; index > 3; index--)
    {
        tempString = string.Format("{0}...", text.Substring(0, index));

        Size tempStringSize = graphic.MeasureString(tempString, font).ToSize();
        if (tempStringSize.Width < availableWidth)
        {
            return tempString;
        }
    }
}
```

The method return incorrect size, not matching the width of the label.

Comment: Did you read the __Remarks__ in the link you gave? Are the problems different from those predicted there? Describe them!

Answer (score 1):

`Graphics.MeasureString` is accurate only if you use `Graphics.DrawString`.

Is it a `Windows.Forms.Label`? Then it uses `Graphics.DrawString` only if `UseCompatibleTextRendering` property is true. Otherwise, you should use `TextRenderer.MeasureText` and `TextRenderer.DrawText` methods instead.

Comment: This is about windows-mobile not winforms!

Comment: @taffer `TextRenderer` is not even available in the Compact Framework.